# Android Location from mobile

Tags: android, android-location

I want to get the location of mobile for my application. i did not want the user to enable the GPS everytime. How can i get the location without asking user to enable gps.Please Give me a solution.

Comment: Have a Look This Location Manager Give u Lat and Loag Using This Get Address of Your Location http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-get-current-latitude-and.html

Comment: that will ask user to enable location.I need location for one activity.So do not want to ask user every time to enable GPS.

Comment: gps.showSettingsAlert(); Comment This Line and Check Code IF Gps In not Enable Thst Time Mobile Network Provider Give Your Location